# Filtering & sorting by dates in MongoDB's oplog

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to filter oplog.rs to view operations that were logged after a certain date. But comparison operators don't seem to work with dates in MongoDB:

```
db['oplog.rs'].find({ts: {$gte: ISODate("2014-12-15T00:00:00Z")}})
```

What's confusing is a lot of online sources are saying to do it this way but it is obviously not working. I want to return results where the ts field is at least December 15th or more recent, but I am getting results that are clearly before this period. If I switch $gte with $lte no results at all are displayed, even though there are definitely entries both before and after this specified date.

Also, I can't seem to sort the results either. If I try this:

```
db['oplog.rs'].find().sort({ts: -1})
```

I get this:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33566005 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes",
    "code" : 17144
}
```

If I could filter the results to make them more recent, I am hoping it would overcome this sorting error, but I can't even do that with MongoDB's basic operators. How can I filter the results of a find operation by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparion operators work just fine with date, but `ts` is a [Timestamp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) object - not a date.

Your query needs to look something like this:

```
db['oplog.rs'].find({ts: {$gte: Timestamp(ISODate("2014-12-15T00:00:00Z").getTime(),0)}})
```

This creates a Timestamp object based on an ISODate and uses it in the query.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it's a timestamp! I don't know how I overlooked that one. However it looks like when you divide by 1000 it's still displaying results from before this date, though if I take out the /1000 it's correctly displaying results from December 15 onwards.

Comment: OK, not dividing by 1000 caused an exception in my test, but if works for you great :)

Comment: why you use inc=0 query.Timestamp(ISODate("2014-12-15T00:00:00Z").getTime(),0).How we decide inc of a timestamp.TimeStamp(time,inc).